# Firefox OS simulator not recognizing device

Tags: firefox, adb, firefox-os

I've got a ZTE Open running Firefox OS that I'd like to push apps to for testing, but the "Push" button doesn't show up in the simulator when I attach the device. I'm running Mac OS 10.8, which apparently shouldn't require any special setup (https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/pushing-a-firefox-os-web-app-to-zte-open-phone/). I ran `adb devices` a few times and saw that the phone was recognized, but inconsistently. I have remote debugging enabled.

The "Push" button appeared beside my apps in the simulator just one time. I pushed an app to the device successfully, then restarted the phone, and the simulator has failed to recognize the phone ever since. I haven't found any helpful documentation or discussion. Mozilla's documentation says that, on Mac OS, all necessary components should work out of the box (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator#Push_to_device).

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Firefox OS simulator is recognizing my device now, but only intermittently. Sometimes it takes three or four un/re-pluggings-in or device restarts, sometimes it recognizes it four or five times in a row. Still, 50% or so is better than nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using a different USB cable to see if that particular cable is a problem?

Comment: I have, yes. At first I thought I'd solved it, too, because I got a connection immediately when I switched cables. But the problem came back right away after that.

Comment: Which version of Firefox, and Firefox OS Simulator are your using? You should also upgrade your ZTE Open to 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in Linux, if you are using Linux first make sure you have

- installed android-tools (if you are using debian or debian based distros then use synaptic to find the packages).
- fire a terminal , navigate to /etc/udev/rules.d , create a new rules file and name it 51-android.rules
  it will have the contents as below:
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

replace "0bb4" with your phone's vendor ID, you can get it by using lsusb in a terminal window.
 - save the file
 - chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules run this thing and then restart udev by typing service udev restart
 - now check adb devices , you will have your device listed ,and it will also be available on firefox OS simulator, if not then make sure your screen lock is off and just disable remote debugging and enable it again .
 - It will be great if you use a latest nightly build of firefox .

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of lucky. On my GNU/Linux, sometimes I couldn't get it working at all using your techniques. But there's something that (almost) always works for me:

```
$ adb kill-server; adb start-server
```

Bingo. It should appear.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. In fact, now it hasn't connected at all, even after two restarts and at least fifteen unpluggings, whereas before it was taking three or four unpluggings to reconnect. It's unfortunate because this makes an already slow testing cycle so much slower.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that sometimes when you connect to the Simulator and you enabled the option to lock the phone, every time when the phone is locked by inactivity time or something the adb connection is killed. Try to see if that is your case, if yes, disable the lock screen by the time you will work with the simulator. It happens to me with the latest commits from Gaia.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I'll try disabling the lock option and see what it does. Lately I've been on an Ubuntu machine which connects just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to push to my ZTE Open after installing firefox nightly (28a2), app manager addon and adb helper addons. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager